# Pass ADDRESS(string) as argument to contract function using web3.py

Tags: solidity, web3.py, python

I've been stuck on this isseu for more then 24 hrs now.

**I have the following function in my solidity contract:**

```
function getBalance(address _addr) public view returns(uint256){
    return userBalance[_addr];
}
```

- I'm trying to check a users balance in my smart contract using an
  *"address"* as a argument. Whenever I pass the address as an argument,
  I receive an error.
- I have another function which doesn't require any arguments, which
  works just fine.

**I am trying to call this function in PYTHON using Web3.py as followed:**

```
contract = self.w3.eth.contract(contract_address, abi=ABI)
addr = '0x0b5b1953752B0C41A59E6B401A13C5816078840A'
print (contract.functions.getBalance(addr).call())
```

**I receive the following error**

```
Could not identify the intended function with name `getBalance`, positional argument(s) of type `(<class 'str'>,)` and keyword argument(s) of type `{}`.
Found 1 function(s) with the name `getBalance`: ['getBalance()']
Function invocation failed due to improper number of arguments.
```

There's no example in the [documentation](https://web3py.readthedocs.io/en/v4.0.0/contracts.html#web3.contract.ContractFunction) which shows me how to pass an address as argument.

**As stated in the comments. I changed my original implementation and forgot to update the ABI. I'm feeling really bad.**

Comment: What version of web3.py are you using? Your documentation link shows 4, but are you really using this version?

Comment: I use Version: 5.12.1

Comment: Also, passing addresses as strings is relevant to web3.js, since JS has a maximum value of safe integer up to 53 bits (where an address is 160 bits). Python doesn't have that limitation, so I would tend to guess that you can (and possibly should) pass the address as a plain number.

Comment: Then you should read the documentation of version 5 and not the documentation of version 4!

Comment: BTW, the error-message tells you that web3.py "Found 1 function(s) with the name `getBalance`: ['getBalance()']", i.e., a function of the same name which doesn't take any input parameters. So perhaps that was your original implementation, then you changed it but did not rebuild your contract, hence web3.py is unaware of this change.

Comment: BTW2, this question is tagged under web3.js, but it has nothing to do with it.

Comment: Thank you so much for taking the time to look with me. You were right, I've changed my original implementation. I feel to stupid right now.